# Linq: When object is null an exception is thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am having difficulty with a query.

```
string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();         
var houseViewModel = this.Data.Houses.All()                
    .Where(u => u.UserId == userId && u.Name == houseName)
    .Select(h => new HouseViewModel
    {                   
        Id = h.Id,
        Name = h.Name,
        ImageUrl = h.ImageUrl,                   
        FloorsViewModel = h.Floоrs.Where(f=>f.Id>0) 
        .Select(f => new FloorViewModel
        {
            Name = f.Name,
            RoomViewModel = f.Rooms.Where(r => r.Id > 0) 
            .Select(r => new RoomViewModel
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                Name = r.Name,                           
                SensorViewModel = new SensorViewModel
                {
                    Id = r.Sensor.Id,
                    CurrentTemp = r.Sensor.CurrentTemp,

                },                           
            })
        })
    })
   .SingleOrDefault();
```

When he came to the room in which no sensor throws exception because `Id` for `SensorViewModel` is a non-nullable  property.

```
SensorViewModel = new SensorViewModel
{ 
    Id = r.Sensor.Id,
```

Comment: I love this syntax (LINQ and object initializer for properties) but...don't you think that **you're not forced** to use it? When it begins to become too hard to read maybe **it's time to go back to old good methods**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SensorViewModel = r.Sensor == null ? new SensorViewModel() : new SensorViewModel
{
  Id = r.Sensor.Id,
  CurrentTemp = r.Sensor.CurrentTemp,
},
```

next try. Simple select only rooms with sensor.

```
  RoomViewModel = f.Rooms.Where(r => r.Id > 0 && r.Sensor != null) 
    .Select(r => new RoomViewModel
    {
        Id = r.Id,
        Name = r.Name,                           
        SensorViewModel = new SensorViewModel
        {
            Id = r.Sensor.Id,
            CurrentTemp = r.Sensor.CurrentTemp,

        },                           
    })
```

last attempt, select data from EF into list and then make viewmodel

```
var house = this.Data.Houses.All()                
    .Where(u => u.UserId == userId && u.Name == houseName).ToList();
var houseViewModel = house.Select(h => new HouseViewModel
    {                   
        Id = h.Id,
        Name = h.Name,
        ImageUrl = h.ImageUrl,                   
        FloorsViewModel = h.Floоrs.Where(f=>f.Id>0) 
        .Select(f => new FloorViewModel
        {
            Name = f.Name,
            RoomViewModel = f.Rooms.Where(r => r.Id > 0) 
            .Select(r => new RoomViewModel
            {
                Id = r.Id,
                Name = r.Name,                           
                SensorViewModel =r.Sensor == null ? null : new SensorViewModel
                {
                    Id = r.Sensor.Id,
                    CurrentTemp = r.Sensor.CurrentTemp,

                },                           
            })
        })
    })
   .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Unable to create a null constant value of type 'SmartHome.Web.Models.SensorViewModel'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

Comment: Fix example - just create new empty SensorViewModel instead of passing null value

Comment: The type 'SmartHome.Web.Models.SensorViewModel' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

Comment: I can't find solution for this problem.

Comment: I add another example - selecting only rows with sensor.

Comment: The sensor in the room is not required. Тhere may be a room without sensor

Comment: Last one try. Select full data from EF and remove EF from next view model creating. I hope, that this.Data.Houses.All() method returns list of houses with all nested collections without future lazy loading.

Comment: Yes, that's one solution, but I wanted to take just fields that I need. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In the result you are getting exactly that you need.